# Matlab how to group time ranges

Tags: matlab, loops, time

I have the following times

```
1.1
1.15
1.19
1.32
1.69
2.12
2.36
2.86
3.25
3.67
3.77
3.91
...
```

And I would like MALTAB to read the times and store the numbers into arrays where array 1 would be for times in 1-2 seconds. Array 2 would be 2-3 seconds and so on.

Thanks in advance for any help/advice given

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) to have those arrays stored as cells of a cell array, like so -

```
groups = accumarray(floor(timeseries),timeseries,[],@(x){x})
```

Sample run -

```
>> timeseries
timeseries =
          1.1
         1.15
         1.19
         1.32
         1.69
         2.12
         2.36
         2.86
         3.25
         3.67
         3.77
         3.91
>> groups = accumarray(floor(timeseries),timeseries,[],@(x){x});
>> celldisp(groups)  %// Display cells of output
groups{1} =
          1.1
         1.15
         1.19
         1.32
         1.69
groups{2} =
         2.12
         2.36
         2.86
groups{3} =
         3.25
         3.67
         3.77
         3.91
```

Comment: Nice use of `accumarray`. Now I wanted to make a `bsxfun` answer but ended up with something else :-)

Answer (score 1):

Let `t` denote your input vector. Then

```
t = sort(t); %// not needed if t is assured to be non-decreasing (as in the example)
result = mat2cell(t(:), diff([0; find(diff([floor(t(:)); NaN]))]));
```

In your example, this gives

```
result{1} =
    1.1000
    1.1500
    1.1900
    1.3200
    1.6900
result{2} =
    2.1200
    2.3600
    2.8600
result{3} =
    3.2500
    3.6700
    3.7700
    3.9100
```

Comment: The next most intuitive way to group such arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact syntax for Matlab but an approach would be to use a floor function on the time variable which will map them to the integer part of your time, then put the ones with the same floor in the same array.