# MATLAB reading a matrix due to conditions of first column

Tags: matlab, matrix, time, plot

Here is a sample of data

```
Time    Data
0.32    1.5
0.45    0.6
0.68    2.1
0.91    0.8
1.23    1.3
1.54    1.0
1.68    2.0
1.92    2.3
1.95    0.7
1.98    1.6
2.12    1.9
2.34    0.3
```

My problem is I want to be able to have all data between the time range 0-0.3 and 0.3-0.6 for example in its own nx2 matrix.  The time always continues to increase. It then would also be nice to set 'n' multiple increase in the bins to save writing 0.3,0.6,0.9,1.2 etc.

I can split the time into the relevant ranges no problem but I do not know how to keep the relevant data with its accompanying time.

I would then want to go on and plot this once I can do the above.

Thanks in advance for any help/suggestions :)

Comment: Is the first column always sorted (increasing)?

Comment: Yes the time is continuously increasing, sorry for not including this info

Comment: I suggest you edit your question to include that information

Comment: What to do when you would have gaps in the first column like after `1.98`, let's say you have `4.2`, `4.3`, thus nothing in that interval of `2-3` and `3-4`?

Comment: Then would a range such as 2-5 not be possible with the answers below? How about if I wanted to split the times that are below 1 second into multiple groups e.g 0.1-0.3, 0.6-0.9

Comment: @user3536870 That would require posted solutions to change, so edit the question to reflect those requirements? Edited my solution in here based on those new requirements.

Comment: Thankyou, I will edit the post now. One final question if you don't mind. Where I have the bins and if the increase was constant e.g 0.3,0.6,0.9 etc is there a way to say to matlab I want 'n' constant increase in bins until the end of the file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the first column contains non-decreasing values, a small modification of [my answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32737452/2586922) will work. Let `data` denote your input matrix and `s` be the step used for defining groups:

```
data = [ 0.32    1.5
         0.45    0.6
         0.68    2.1
         0.91    0.8
         1.23    1.3
         1.54    1.0
         1.68    2.0
         1.92    2.3
         1.95    0.7
         1.98    1.6
         2.12    1.9
         2.34    0.3 ]; %// example data
s = .3; %// step to define groups
```

Then

```
result = mat2cell(data, diff([0; find(diff([floor(data(:,1)/s); NaN]))]) , size(data,2));
```

gives

```
result{1} =
    0.3200    1.5000
    0.4500    0.6000
result{2} =
    0.6800    2.1000
result{3} =
    0.9100    0.8000
result{4} =
    1.2300    1.3000
result{5} =
    1.5400    1.0000
    1.6800    2.0000
result{6} =
    1.9200    2.3000
    1.9500    0.7000
    1.9800    1.6000
result{7} =
    2.1200    1.9000
    2.3400    0.3000
```

Note that if some group is not present in the input it will simply be skipped in the result. For example,

```
data = [ 0.32    1.5
         0.45    0.6
         0.68    2.1
         2.12    1.9
         2.34    0.3 ]; %// example data
s = .3;  %// step to define groups
```

will produce

```
result{1} =
    0.3200    1.5000
    0.4500    0.6000
result{2} =
    0.6800    2.1000
result{3} =
    2.1200    1.9000
    2.3400    0.3000
```

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to define custom bin edges for binning rows of input array, here's one approach with [`histcounts`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histcounts.html) and [`arrayfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html) -

```
bin_edges = [0.3,0.6,1,12 15]; %// Define bin edges here
[~,~,bins] = histcounts(A(:,1),bin_edges);
groups = arrayfun(@(n) A(bins==n,:),1:max(bins),'Uni',0);
```

Sample input, output -

```
>> A
A =
         0.32          1.5
         0.45          0.6
         0.68          2.1
         0.91          0.8
         1.23          1.3
         1.54            1
         1.68            2
         1.92          2.3
         1.95          0.7
         1.98          1.6
        12.12          1.9
        12.34          0.3
>> celldisp(groups)    %// Display cells of output
groups{1} =
         0.32          1.5
         0.45          0.6
groups{2} =
         0.68          2.1
         0.91          0.8
groups{3} =
         1.23          1.3
         1.54            1
         1.68            2
         1.92          2.3
         1.95          0.7
         1.98          1.6
groups{4} =
        12.12          1.9
        12.34          0.3
```

Comment: This will give empty groups if there are gaps in your `id` (caused by large gaps in the first column of `A`). To solve that I suggest `[~, ~, id] = unique(floor(A(:,1)))`. +1 anyway

Comment: @LuisMendo Yeah that's sort of the ongoing behavior issue I have from the last post by OP on how to handle such cases. Posted a comment for OP on this.

Comment: Both answers gave me the exact and same result I was after. Sorry that I can only award the correct answer to one person! +1 though all the same

Comment: @user3536870 No worries really!

Comment: Also would like to say thanks for helping on my previous question today, I appreciate the help!